# usb installation not working properly

Tags: usb, usb-installation

I have installed ubuntu from usb so do I need to use that usb in future launches? Cause when I dont it always starts windows and when i use usb it gives me only option to try ubuntu or install ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GRUB was not installed when you installed ubuntu to your hard disk. You should be able to fix by using Boot-Repair, follow the instructions Link here>  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   After using Boot-Repair it will give you the option of which Operating system you would like to use, Ubuntu or Windows :-) Just follow directions on Link that I posted.  Be patient it might seem as tho the operation has frozen, but let it work it's Magic and you Will be HAPPY :-)    Don't forget to reboot :-)